# Loading Jar is painfully slow on Apache, not on Serweb

Tags: java, performance, apache, applet, loading

I'm in the process of changing the web server from Serweb to Apache. The website contains java applet ( in jar form - java6 ) that didn't have any trouble loading with Serweb, but take over half a minute to load with Apache.

I suppose there is something wrong with Apache configuration but I didn't find anything related. Is there some other issue? How can I fix this?

Comment: So after hours of search i came to the conclusion that it was not or hardware problem, nor a html problem and even less a MIME type problem.

Turns out that changing KeepAlive to Off in /etc/apache2/apache.conf solve the problem. I should probably investigate the root cause of this in the java, but for now it works for me.